Problem in Uchida's Theorem
I m studying relative class number of CM fields and i found a very interesting theorem from Kόji Uchida's article: class numbers of imaginary abelian fields (1970) but one argument of the demonstration is not clear for me.
The Theorem is as follow
Let $k$ be an imaginary normal extension of the rational
number field $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. Let $d$ be the absolute value of its discriminant.
We assume that the maximal real subfield $k_0$ of $k$ is also normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Then the first factor $h_1=h/h_0$ of the class number is arbitrarily large, if $n/\log d$
is sufficiently small.
Here $h$ and $h_0$ are class numbers of $k$ and $k_0$ respectively.
As $k_0$ is normal, the unit group of $k$ has a subgroup of finite index $q$ generated by the units of $k_0$ and the roots of unity of $k$. In fact we can say that $q\le 2$ for CM-fields.
Moreover we have the relation between the regulators $$qR=2^{n/2-1}R_0.$$
The first part of the demonstration is clear,
Proof. Above remark shows
$$
h R \leq h_1 h_0 \cdot 2^{n / 2} R_0 .
$$
It is known that there exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$
\frac{\log h_0 R_0}{\log \sqrt{d_0}} \leq C
$$
for any $k_0$. (The left hand side is $0 / 0$ for $k_0=\mathbb{Q}$, but no trouble is caused in the following). If $\log d_0 / \log d<1 / 2 C$, it holds
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\log h R}{\log \sqrt{d}} \leq \frac{\log h_1 h_0 2^{n / 2} R_0}{\log \sqrt{d}} \\
& =\frac{\log h_1+n \log 2 / 2+\log h_0 R_0}{\log \sqrt{d}} \\
\leq & \frac{\log h_1}{\log \sqrt{d}}+\frac{n \log 2}{\log d}+\frac{\log h_0 R_0}{2 C \log \sqrt{d_0}} \\
\leq & \frac{\log h_1}{\log \sqrt{d}}+\frac{n \log 2}{\log d}+\frac{1}{2} .
\end{aligned}
$$
The second inequality does not hold if $k_0=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\log h_0 R_0<0$ in the above. But the last inequality holds also in these cases.
If $n / \log d$ is sufficiently small, Brauer-Siegel theorem shows that
$$
\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{\log h_1}{\log \sqrt{d}}
$$
If $\log d_{0} / \log d \geq 1 / 2 C$, it holds
$$\mathbf{\frac{\log h R}{\log \sqrt{d}} \leq \frac{\log h_1}{\log \sqrt{d}}+\frac{n \log 2}{\log d}+\frac{\log h_0 R_0}{2 \log \sqrt{d_0}}}
$$
If $n / \log d$ is sufficiently small, $n / \log d_0$ is small enough. Then it also holds
$$
\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{\log h_1}{\log \sqrt{d}}
$$
Theferore it holds
$$
\frac{1}{3} \log \sqrt{d} \leq \log h_1,
$$
if $n / \log d$ is sufficiently small. Then $\log \sqrt{d}$ is large, and $\log h_1$ becomes large arbitrarily.
The problem comes when we suppose $\log(d_0)/\log(d)\ge\frac{1}{2C}$
I don't know why the last part of the inegality is right.
How can we have this inequality with just the assumption $\log d_{0} / \log d \geq 1 / 2 C$

The more i read the proof the more i think there is a mistake...

I do not think that a paper exactly matching your citation exists, but there is Uchida - Class numbers of imaginary abelian number fields, I from 1971.  Is that the one you meant?

Yes, it is the Theorem 1 of this paper. Am I wrong in my interpretation?

Re, I wasn't meaning to say anything about the interpretation, just to make sure I knew what the paper was.

I confirm it s the correct one :)

I think I have the solution.
If we consider the relative discriminant $d_{k/k_0}$, then $d=\mathcal{N}(d_{k/k_0})d_0^2$ because the extension $k/k_0$ is of degree 2. Then, as the absolute norm is greater or equal than 1, $\log(d)\ge2\log(d_0)$.
So
$$\frac{1}{\log(\sqrt{d})}\le\frac{1}{2\log(\sqrt{d_0})}.$$
